# PYQGIS tool to get Raster XYZ data from inside Polygon?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am working on automating a process to overlay a polygon on a raster layer and get the data inside polygon for calculations. Is there a method to extract the XYZ data of the raster that is inside the polygon?